# c - writing to shared memory segment causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, shared-memory

I'm having problems with writing to shared memory segment. Here's the code:

EDIT: after I removed that == (mistake), now I'm getting Bus Error (Core Dumped), here's the edited code:

```
// Struct for data from shared memory
typedef struct {
     pthread_mutex_t shared_mutex;
     int last_used_job_id;
} shared1;

static void *job_generator(void *param)
{
     int J = *((int *) param);
     shared1 *shd;
     int shm;
     int job_id;

     // Open shared memory, don't create it if doesn't exist
     shm = shm_open("/lab5", O_RDWR, 00600);

     // Check
     if (shm == -1) {
          // Open shared memory, create it if doesn't exist (O_CREAT)
         shm = shm_open(q_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 00600);

         // Map space for struct
         shd = mmap(NULL, sizeof(shared1), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm, 0); 
         if (shd == (void *) -1) {
              perror ( "mmap" );
              exit(1);
         }

         // Initialize mutex
         if (pthread_mutex_init(&(shd->shared_mutex), NULL) != 0)
         {
              printf("Mutex initialization failed!\n");
              exit(1);
         }
     }

     else
     {
          // Map space for struct
          shd = mmap(NULL, sizeof(shared1), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm, 0);    
          if (shd == (void *) -1) {
              perror ( "mmap" );
              exit(1);
          } 
     }

     // Lock mutex
     pthread_mutex_lock(&(shd->shared_mutex));

     job_id = shd->last_used_job_id + 1;
     shd->last_used_job_id = job_id + J;
     printf("a: %d\n", shd->last_used_job_id);

     return NULL;
}
```

it's caused by any of the instructions which are using shd, so any of these:

```
// Lock mutex
pthread_mutex_lock(&(shd->shared_mutex));

job_id = shd->last_used_job_id + 1;
shd->last_used_job_id = job_id + J;
printf("a: %d\n", shd->last_used_job_id);
```

Comment: `shd == mmap` ???  It does something, but I am pretty sure not what you want.

Comment: @fvu And this is why we compile with warnings enabled.

Comment: @Nemo yes, *we* do that, religiously even :) I am always perplexed when people tell me they switched off warnings "because they were so noisy".  Go figure.

Comment: oh well, seems that I'm stupid... I was so tired that I missed this mistake even if I passed a few times through the code...

Comment: but now I'm getting Bus Error (Core Dumped) and it's caused by any of the code which is using shd after mapping. I changed my question with new problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is where your problem lies:

```
shd == mmap(NULL, sizeof(shared1), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm, 0);
```

You're comparing shd to the return value of mmap with '=='. I think you meant to use a single '=' which would assign the return value to shd.

Comment: oh well, seems that I'm stupid... I was so tired that I missed this mistake even if I passed a few times through the code...

Comment: but now I'm getting Bus Error (Core Dumped) and it's caused by any of the code which is using shd after mapping. I changed my question with new problem!

Comment: I'm not sure just by looking at the code. Have you tried commenting out each line one at a time, starting with pthread_mutex_lock?

Comment: I corrected the mistake but I'm not sure right now where it was :D (the code is on Ubuntu and I'm currently on Windows so can't check) I think it was something with calling shm_open, wrong parameters or something. Thanks!